# Jenkins, Zuul and Gearman

Tags: jenkins, gearman

I'm new to Openstack and having issues in integrating Zuul, gearman and Jenkins.

I installed gerrit and zuul from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zuul/2.1.0
Gearman from gearman.org and also installed Gearman plugin on Jenkins master.

Now, they are listening to each other but I'm not able to trigger the Jenkins job.

Is there any good configuration document available online? or someone have the solution? Not sure at this point, what I'm doing wrong.

Regards
Sammi

Comment: Have you checked the jenkins plugin documentation: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin

Comment: Thanks Spieker for replying and yes, I read the documentation. Looks like the issue is now resolved, job are getting triggered but I'm not sure at this point that they are correct or not. The zuul-merger daemon was missing.